# statically typed, embeddable, compilable scripting langage

Tags: scripting-language, compiled-language

I'm lookign for a langage with the following features :

- SWIG-compatible, or similar. Compatibility with C++ should be easy :

> C, C++, AllegroCL, C# - Mono, C# - MS
>   .NET, CFFI, CHICKEN, CLISP, D, Go
>   , Guile, Java, Lua,
>   MzScheme/Racket, Ocaml, Octave, Perl,
>   PHP, Python, R, Ruby, Tcl/Tk

- Statically typed : No *myObject.CompletelyNewFieldWithUnknownSideEffects = GuessWhat()* like in Lua. No *isinstance()* like in php. No *newVariableOfUnknownType = foo()* like in Python.  Preferably strongly typed, too ( "Hello"+"0" rather than "Hello"+0 ) :

> C, C++,   C#, D, Go, Java, Ocaml, PHP, Ruby ? Other ?

- Can be compiled at runtime ( and exec("gcc plugin.cpp")! doesn't count ! ) into whatever asm/intermediate langage.

> C : libCLang, Ch; C++ : Ch; Any scripting langage; Other ?

- Can be compiled (either offline or at runtime) into a x86 .dll/.so, OR .cpp

> C : gcc, libClang, etc; C++; C#; D; Python; Go; OCaml; Lua : LuaJIT; Ruby : Ludicrous

- Preferably with debugger :)

TL;DR

I would like a statically typed, embeddable scripting langage which can be compiled for perf.

Ideas ? Comments ? Input of any kind ? Thanks !

**EDIT** Valid propositions so far :

- Java : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html
- C# : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655/en-us
- C++, interpreted by Ch, compiled with usual compiler , hopefully compatible with GCC/VC
- Racket : http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/inside/overview.html#%28part._embedding%29

So there is much more hope than I originally thought :) Thank you all ! I'll keep investigating and will accept an answer when I have more experience on the subject.

Comment: Racket ships with a statically-typed language - Typed Racket, but I do not know it interoperates with SWIG.

Comment: I'm curious why you say "exec("gcc plugin.cpp") doesn't count!"  Combine it with dlopen, and you've got an entirely functional way of compiling code and running it from within the process that compiled it.  It's a bit heavy on filesystem use, admittedly, but it ought to work fine other than that.

Comment: It would work... on MY machine. Reboot on Windows : doesn't work. No Cygwin : doesn't work. Bad gcc version : doesn't work. Bad file permissions : doesn't work. PATH not correct : doesn't work.

Comment: On Windows you will need to ship your program with MinGW just like Git ships with MSYS. There is another problem you will need to build your C++ program with MinGW and not with Visual C++ since ABI of the compilers differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Ruby is in each of your lists, and the [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) compiler compiles it down to bytecode. Does that meet your needs?</strike>

2nd try:   Have you looked at [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/):  "an object oriented statically typed programming language for the Common Language Infrastructure"

Comment: Ruby isn't statically typed, so no.

Comment: Boo doesn't seem to be easily embeddable from C++. But you have a good point though : .NET seems good for this, and you can compile C# from C# : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655/en-us

Comment: Accepted as solution. Not for Boo but for C#, which can be embedded through SWIG, and compiled on the fly with Mono : http://docs.go-mono.com/Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Compile%20%28string%29 .

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly not a useful answer, but Java does actually fit all your bullet points.

- You can talk to native code with JNI, JNA, or SWIG.
- As statically typed as it gets without needing a PhD
- Can be compiled at runtime through the [compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/package-summary.html)
- Is compiled to native code at runtime by some excellent compilers (and there are offline compilers too)
- Has a number of debuggers

The problem is that it's not exactly a scripting language; you need to write quite a lot of boilerplate to get a small task done, and the APIs are usually fairly involved.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at OpenCL, perhaps?  It's designed around being a C-like language that is compiled at runtime, but AMD's latest SDKs provide the ability to do offline pre-compilation as well.

It's not an obvious choice, because it's promoted for use on GPUs, but it's designed to be more broadly-applicable than that and can be run just as well on ordinary CPUs.

Comment: +1 for unexpected, original and clever answer. I'll need more time to form a better opinion though :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it's possible to call C++ functions from a kernel. This is a no-go for a scripting language. Too bad.

Comment: You're right; I'd missed that part of the requirements.  I think you may be able to call inline C++ functions to some extent, but calling non-inline C++ (or C, for that matter) code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure D is compilable and can be run as a script.

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is no mean to compile D from C++, unless I missed something.

Comment: Why would you want to "compile" to C++?

Comment: Not "to C++". I want to be able to write something like that in C++ : prog = CompileDProgram("blah.d"); prog.executeDFunction("some_function"). Like I do in Boost::Python or Luabind.